# Passing the Event Object to a Function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, function, parameters

Typically, I can pass an event to an anonymous Jquery function like so:

```
$(".click_me").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now let's say I remove the anonymous function but still want to pass the event to it:

```
function onClickMe(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}

$(".click_me").on("click", onClickMe(e));
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as expected. I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: e is not defined
```

So how else can I pass the event to an external function?

Comment: That's an _anonymous_ function, not an "internal" one.

Comment: @MattBall Thanks for the tip. I've corrected my question. On a similar note, is there a proper term for what I call "external functions"?

Comment: @timothythehuman Probably just called a function, though an example would help.

Comment: The terms are "anonymous" and "named." Way more than you ever wanted to know: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just pass the function reference, jQuery will handle passing the arguments for you (it *always* passes the event as the first argument to the handler function). So:

```
function onClickMe(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}

$(".click_me").on("click", onClickMe);
```

Comment: Brilliant! I had no idea Jquery was so elegant.

Comment: Confused here - preventDefault() is a jQuery function (not internal jscript one). How come then we call it without the $  I would have expected
 $(e).preventDefault()

Comment: @DavidThorisson Because the paramater `e` in the function is passed a jQuery Event object when the event fires, which has the `preventDefault()` function.

Comment: That works but I'm still looking for a way so that I can pass event and my own parameter in the same function, something like `$(".click_me").on("click", onClickMe(event, parameter1));`